# AJAX error thrown when a JIRA Issue Collector form is plugged into a site

Tags: php, jira

I am getting the following error when I add the code below to my site. I'm not too familiar with JIRA or web development so any help would be appreciated.

Error:

> Oops! Something went wrong... AJAX error thrown: SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token < Don't worry though! We've logged this problem and
>   will look into it soon!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS =  {
    "triggerFunction": function(showCollectorDialog\) {
        //Requires that jQuery is available! 
        jQuery(".feedback-form"\).click(function(e\) {
            e.preventDefault(\);
            showCollectorDialog(\);
        \}\);
    \}\};
</script>
)
```

Comment: Why are all of the right parens "\"-escaped? Depending on where you're sticking this stuff, they probably should not be.

Comment: That is actually what we need to do in our code as escape characters.

Comment: You only need to escape right parens and not left parens?! (When I write my own language some day, I will force my users to escape only every sixth "%".)

Comment: Yeah, only the right parens are closed out :/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still an issue, but it's important to note that the JIRA Issue Collector plugin **is associated with a user**. The error mentioned in the question was thrown for us because the username of this associated user was changed after the plugin was created and added to the site.

I assume this happens because the plugin is trying to create a ticket and set the author as the username that was changed/doesn't exist anymore.

To fix this, try changing the username back to what it originally was and test the plugin.